# Clarification on proof of converging sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Can someone explain a proof that a certain sequence converges by using the Archimedean property, such as the following.

> Prove that ${a_n} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ is a sequence that converges to $a=0$ for $n \to \infty$.
>
> Definition: If $a_n$ converges to $a$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an index $N$ such that $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.
>
> Proof by the Archimedean property:
>
> Let $\varepsilon >0$ be fixed. By the Archimedean property, there exists an $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$. Since for all $n \geq N$, $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{N}$, we have $|a_n - 0| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Ergo, $\big\{\frac{1}{n+1}\big\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$.

A few questions:

1. Why is it necessary to state that $n \geq N$?
2. Since $n$ and $N$ are both suppose to be natural numbers, why is it that Archimedean can’t directly imply $\frac{1}{n} \geq \varepsilon$?
3. My main confusion is with indexes, if someone could explain to me why we compare an index $n$ to some natural number $N$, that would be nice.

Also, apologies for the poor formatting, I’m still new to stack exchange.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to type mathematical symbol, such as $\epsilon$, type like this `$\epsilon$`

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have clarified the proof you gave. Hope that helps you understand the proof.

It seems that you don't fully understand the definition of convergence (or limit of a sequence). The definition of $a_n \to a$ is that, for **any** $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find a number $N$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for **all** $n \geq N$. In other words, the sequence converges if the "tail" of $a_n$ gets arbitrarily closer to $a$ as $n \to \infty$.

In order to prove this, we first fix an $\varepsilon > 0$, and then try to find an $N$ so that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. If we can find this number $N$, then the claim in the definition is proven because the $\varepsilon$ we fix is arbitrary. Now the Archimedean property helps us find this $N$.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful

Comment: @WeiHuang Glad I could help.